# Getting undefined while accessing result of mongoDB insertOne from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, error-handling, server, mongodb-query

I am trying to access documents through insert one method in mongoDB in Nodejs . But I am getting undefined in the console

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb')

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient
const connectURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'

const databaseName = 'Task-Manager'

MongoClient.connect(connectURL , {useNewUrlParser : true } , (error , client )=>{

    if(error)
    {
        return console.log("Unable to connect to database")
    }

    const db = client.db(databaseName)

    db.collection('Users').insertOne({
        id: 12820,
        Name: "karthik",
        age : 20
    } , (error , result)=>{

        if(error)
        {
        return console.log("error has occured ")
        }
        console.log(result.ops)// I am getting undefined if i print  the document in console
    })

})
```

Comment: Kindly go through some mongoDB tutorial, just one for reference is https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIfcYFqzDXHkSPsm1DfMuA0TEgpycA2e1

Comment: @Karthik, if answer is working then mark that as confirm otherwise write here if still you are facing problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to print like below

```
console.log(result.ops)
```

But there is nothing like "ops" in result object.

The shape of result object is like below

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: new ObjectId("620ac763da37bbb06c9472a1")
}
```

Means, mongoDB just send back the Aknowledgement and insertedId (This is the objectId of the document inserted).

So, if you also want the document then you need to add code to find data with this Object ID like below.

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb')

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient
const connectURL = 'mongodb+srv://mongoclass:newpass@myclass.fczoc.mongodb.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

const databaseName = 'Task-Manager'

MongoClient.connect(connectURL , {useNewUrlParser : true } , (error , client )=>{

    if(error)
    {
        return console.log("Unable to connect to database")
    }

    const db = client.db(databaseName)

    db.collection('Users').insertOne({
        id: 12820,
        Name: "karthik",
        age : 20
    } , (error , result)=>{

        if(error)
        {
        return console.log("error has occured ")
        }
        // changes are below
        db.collection('Users').findOne({_id:result.insertedId})
        .then((data) =>{
            console.log(data);
        } )
        .catch((err) =>{
            console.log(err);
        })
    })

})
```

Then it will give the data as below

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("620ac88a1471142775a484b5"),
  id: 12820,
  Name: 'karthik',
  age: 20
}
```